# Compile and load QGIS3 plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, plugins, development

`Win7 x64`, `QGIS 3.4` installed through `OSGeo4W` with 'Advanced Install'

Here's my workflow:

1. Get the template directory from `PluginBuilder3`
2. Navigate to this folder in the `OSGeo4W Shell`
3. Use `call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qt5_env.bat"` otherwise `pyrcc5` is unavailable
4. Use `pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`  as suggested in `pluginbuilder3` help - note that a `resources.qrc` file already exists. This steps does not produce an error but does not seem to produce anything either.
5. Use `make` - this gives the following message:

   > make: Nothing to be done for 'defaults'.
6. Use `make test` - this gives the following message:

   > chmod: cannot acces 'scripts/compile-strings.sh': No such file or directory
   >   make: *** [transcompile] Error 1

I try to copy the plugin directory at `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins` but it is not seen by `QGIS` or `Plugin Reloader`

*UPDATE:*
- there is no sub-directory in the plugin folder - isn't a `i18n` folder expected ?
- at step 4 `resources.py` is updated but `resources.qrc` is left unchanged

Answer (score 4):

The compilation is going to be tested with the following example where icon enclosed in the red rectangle (see image), from one test plugin (makingmultiplebuffers), will be changed for one qgis-icon (24x24 pixels) created for this example.

[image]

Path to plugin is:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\makingmultiplebuffers
```

So, old icon name (icon.png) will be modified to qgis-icon.png in **metadata.txt**, **resources.qrc** and initGui method of main py file of plugin (in my case **making_multiple_buffers.py**). Completed all changes, I ran following commands at **OSGeo4W** shell:

```
cd C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\makingmultiplebuffers
call qt5_env.bat 
call py3_env.bat
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

and it can be observed at following image, after using reloading qgis plugin, that icon was efectively changed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I don't even get to the first step. The plugin isn't recognized by QGIS from the start.